# What is the purpose of this long capacitor/inductor chain on a DDS IC evaluation board?

Tags: amplifier, analog, high-frequency, dds

[image: Image of the B output stage of the AD9834 DDS EV board]

Image of the B output stage of the [EVAL-CN0304 AD9834 DDS Evaluation Board](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/ug-266.pdf)

IOUT_B is a current source, not potential source, so the initial say half of the circuit I get. The resistor gives us a proportional voltage, where it is centred on the input range + put through a unity gain amplifier, so we do not load down the input + cause issues. What I don't get then is why it is put through this 51 ohm voltage divider and all these capacitors and inductors.  It seems like this would create a bunch of nasty resonant peaks from the LC oscillators.

Comment: Elliptical lowpass filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your circuit is a low pass circuit with a very sharp cut-off at about 17.8 MHz. The sharp cut-off is due to the high order of the filter.

The output of the circuit probably goes to a 50\$\Omega\$ transmission line, which is itself terminated with a 50 \$\Omega\$ termination resistor. The 51 \$\Omega\$ resistors would then be for impedance matching, to prevent reflections back into the amplifier part of the circuit, or back into the transmission line.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0LbYq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: This confuses me further then, this is a DDS that can produce up to 37.5MHz signals, why would they choose values to give a cutoff so much lower than the output?